# (WkWebView) When do i upload file by input tag, it happened problem

Tags: swift, ios13

I use WKWebView.

recently i update my iPhone to ios13

then something wrong...

1. touch input(type=file) tag.
2. appear select photo in library or take a picture modal.
3. one of these action i act. return the black screen.

what should i do?

Help me. please~

Thank you for reading.

[detail pic of 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWWrB.png)

[detail pic of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELdor.jpg)

[detail pic of 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1lOF.png)

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/32408352

Answer (score 1):

i solve this problem

i caught default imagePicker in wkwebview (override present func)

and modalStyle set .custom

then it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question with a workaround for this bug. It saved my bacon!